# Find hiearachy region image

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, image-segmentation

Let say I have a labeled image, which means for each pixel I have a value between 0 and 8 if I have 8 region in the image.

Now what I want to do is to find the hierarchy of the labels in the same way that cv2.findcontour do for the contours.

Example : 
 [image: Logo mcdo]

Let say I have segmented this logo in two regions (green and yellow). I want to extract the information that the yellow part is inside the green part.

opencv do that very well with the contours but I don't know how to do it with regions ...

Comment: Follow the yellow contour and check if they are completely surrounded by the green region.

Comment: Not sure how general or how specific you need this... do you ever have more than 8 regions? Do you need to know for each and every region whether it is wholly contained within any one of the others - which could take a lot longer - or do you want to just now if region X is wholly in region Y - or do you want to know if region X is wholly inside region A or B or C - or do you want to know region X is not wholly in any other region because its edges touch more than other region?

Comment: Note that your image with 2 regions above contains 258 unique colours so there is something going wrong with your processing already.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I want to know the level of every region. I can have until 256 regions. For example, if there are 2 regions, and the second one is inside the first region, then the region "1" is at level 0 and region "2" is at level 1. however if it's just two regions next to each other, then both will be level "0".

You are right about the image, it was just a visual example. I do a quantization after to only have n regions.

Comment: Your explanation confuses me further :-) I thought you wanted to know, for each region, which region fully contains it, but now I think you just want to know which level each region is on. So if you have a green background with a yellow B and blue K on it, and inside the yellow B there is a pink circle and inside the blue K there is a grey circle, do you just want to know that the pink circle and the grey circle are on the same level, or do you need to know which letter contains each one?

Comment: I want to know that the pink circle and the grey circle are on the same level. So the green background should be level 0. bluk k and yellow B level 1. pink circle  and grey circle : level 2. 

Is more clear ? ^^